# How do I get quick lists in unity shipped in 11.10?

Tags: 11.04, unity, 11.10

I have delightfully seen the list of quick-lists for major applications (firefox, chrome, libre office, banshee, etc.) thriving in these days for Ubuntu Natty. It is a great idea that is really useful and help many to simplify their workflow.

My question is: will these quick-lists be included (and of course improved) by default in Ubuntu Oneiric? By improved I mean adding a dynamic quick-list for the home folder icon in the launcher, for example (the one that changes  every time you change your bookmarks in nautilus).

Answer (score 1):

One way to help with this is to [file a wishlist bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on the component that you want a static quicklist for and include the .desktop file. Then tag the bug with `quicklist` so we can keep track of the bugs.

We're tracking the status of these bugs on [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerUsers/Quicklists).

For programs that might not live in Launchpad a *friendly* wishlist request in their bug tracker with the snippet from the .desktop file could work.

However I only recommend doing that for the "long tail" of little programs that people are using. Large programs that we ship by default, like Nautilus and Firefox, will need support for dynamic playlists instead.

So for example we can't just ship a .desktop for Nautilus with the handy shortcuts. We need Nautilus to support any shortcut the user defines in the program so that it's always showing the user's favorites, even if the change them. For browsers they'll need to do like "the last X websites" or "last X tabs you closed" or whatever their design criteria is.

However for most little tools a static quicklist can be a nice little bit of Unity integration so contacting app authors and showing them the work you've done would be quite useful.